# Unable to access api exposed by istio cluster on AKS. I can see external ip and ports but unable to reach the same

Tags: azure-aks, istio, istio-gateway

Followed this example

https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/ Below is output from istioctl analyze

output of istioctl analyze

[output of istioctl anayze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMsjZ.png)

Updated port number and selector as suggested by istioctl tool. But still on dead end

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  # The selector matches the ingress gateway pod labels.
  # If you installed Istio using Helm following the standard documentation, this would be "istio=ingress"
  selector:
    istio: ingress # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello [gera1390](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8333546/gera1390) your steps are correct, there is a glitch in the document. I tried the same [document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/) shared by you and found the same issue.

Downloaded istio
[image]

installed Istio
[image]

added a namespace label

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
```

[image]

Deployed in bookinfo sample

```
kubectl apply -f [samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.20/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml)
```

[image]

verified the service and pods

```
kubectl get services
kubectl get pods
```

[image]

associated the bookinfo with gateway

```
 kubectl apply -f [samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.20/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml)
```

[image]

Analyzed it using `istioctl analyze`
[image]

Got the external IP

```
kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

[image]

Set the ingress IP and ports and exported the gateway url

```
export GATEWAY_URL=$INGRESS_HOST:$INGRESS_PORT
```

[image]
[image]

In this entire setup, I made sure there is no firewall enabled, my NSG rules are allowing port 80 and 443
[image]

**Instead, you can try the below alternative options**-

Option 1-
localhost approach, I tried using localhost and I was able to access it over the localhost-
Deployment process remains the same. You create a cluster.
[image]

Create a namespace for bookinfo

```
kubectl create namespace bookinfo
```

[image]

Deploy the application as already shown above
[image]

Once deployed, verify the pods-
[image]

Do a port forward using `kubectl port-forward -n bookinfo service/productpage 9090`
[image]

and access it via localhost

[image]

Option2-
As per this [setup](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/microservices-istio/bookinfo-kubernetes/)
Update your  `/etc/hosts`  configuration file In your `/etc/hosts` file, add the previous IP address to the host entries provided by the following command.

```
echo $(kubectl get ingress istio-system -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{..ip} {..host}') $(kubectl get ingress bookinfo -o jsonpath='{..host}')
```

You should have a [Superuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) privilege and probably use [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to edit `/etc/hosts`.

and access the application’s home page from the command line:

```
kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -c sleep -- curl -sS productpage:9080/productpage | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"
```

[image]

Reference Document-

[Bookinfo sample](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/microservices-istio/bookinfo-kubernetes/)

[Getting started with istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/)